# Nesting OMP DO directives - Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm having problems trying to nest a OMP DO directive inside another OMP DO directive in Fortran.

Here's the following code:

```
DO in=2,n_niveles
    allocate(cvalor(2,npuntosp(in),npuntost(in)))
    !allocate(avalor(2,npuntosp(in-1),npuntost(in-1)))
    allocate(valor_t2(npuntost(in),npuntosp(in-1),2))
    !$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(hilos) DEFAULT(PRIVATE) FIRSTPRIVATE(n_niveles,in) SHARED(npuntosp,npuntost,cubos,central_reg,sumazm1n,expo,mphi,mtheta)
    !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)
    DO aux=1,cubos(in-1)%ncubos_nivel
       ...
       (some code here)
       ...
       !$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(hilos) DEFAULT(PRIVATE) FIRSTPRIVATE(cuboj,in) SHARED(valor_t2,cvalor)
       !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)                
       do i=1,npuntost(in) 
           val=mtheta(in-1)%inicio(i,1) 
           do jj=val,val+mtheta(in-1)%inicio(i,2) 
               do k=1,npuntosp(in-1) 
                   valor_t2(i,k,1)=valor_t2(i,k,1)+mtheta(in-1)%matriz(i,jj)*sumazm1n(in-1)%region(cuboj)%valor(1,k,jj)   
                   valor_t2(i,k,2)=valor_t2(i,k,2)+mtheta(in-1)%matriz(i,jj)*sumazm1n(in-1)%region(cuboj)%valor(2,k,jj)        
               end do
           end do 

           do k=1,npuntosp(in) 
               val=mphi(in-1)%inicio(k,1) 
               do jj=val,val+mphi(in-1)%inicio(k,2)
                   cvalor(1,k,i)=cvalor(1,k,i)+valor_t2(i,jj,1)*mphi(in-1)%matriz(jj,k)
                   cvalor(2,k,i)=cvalor(2,k,i)+valor_t2(i,jj,2)*mphi(in-1)%matriz(jj,k)
               end do
           end do 
       end do
       !$OMP END DO
       !$OMP END PARALLEL

       ...
       (some code here)
       ...
    END DO
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
    deallocate(cvalor)
    deallocate(valor_t2)
END DO
```

When the code is executed, an access violation exception occurs inside the second OpenMP parallel region. Sometimes that exception is changed for an overflow at the variable valor_t2.

Maybe OpenMP does not support this kind of parallelization, but I've searched over the net and didn't found anything about. I know that OpenMP supports the use of various OMP PARALLEL directives nested one inside another and I know how it works. But I'm having a headache with this problem.

Any ideas about what it's happening?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try a debugger (or a race condition detector)? A code snippet, that can be compiled, would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use the `collapse` clause in the do loop at the top level. See the link below for information:

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/

As long as the code represented by `(some code here)` doesn't contain any loops, this should work.

Comment: Reminds me last two days blindly debugging to find out the implementation of `collapse` in unnamed largest commercial Fortran compiler is buggy.

Comment: But +1, thanks for the hint there can be some code between the loops. Although there still can be issues, whether the privatization the OP needs can be achieved.

Comment: Not to put undue pressure on you, @VladimirF, but naming the compiler might help OP if he/she is using it. Maybe a private message?

Comment: I've tried the use of collapse and does not work well with the code. In the second part of `(some code here)`, there are more loops(sorry for that, I never imagined that that would have importance). The idea is that each thread launch more threads to calculate what is inside of the mentioned loop.

Comment: I think it would help to post the entire code, or a minimal example that demonstrates what you're trying to do. I'd like to see if the loops can be re-arranged in such a way that the `collapse` clause can be of use. 

You may also want to measure the code's performance with only one of the loops parallelized (either inner or outer), to see if near-optimal performance can be obtained without parallelizing both.

Comment: It is Intel Fortran. They still did not make any attempt to solve that bug after more than a year https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/509671